# Positionning Target's automatic recognition in Blender

Tags: objects

thanks in advance for any the help. I'm new to Blender and pretty new to 3D scanning.

For a project - which I'd be happy to detail but I'm not sure it is relevant - I would like some specific spots on my 3D scanned subject to be automatically picked up by Blender. Say I have a dude's face with a bike helmet on, well I need some specific points on the helmet's surface to be recognized by Blender (e.g. by having a vertex assigned to them in a particular vertex group, which is what I mean by recognize / picked up). Of course I could import the 3D scan and manually go over the helmet and define vertices wherever I want them to be, and add them to a vertex group, but that seems cumbersome to me. So in summary what I want to do is: to 3D scan a shape (guy's face + helmet on) and then import it into Blender in a way that specific spots are recognized / rendered / picked up / assigned a vertex in a particular fashion. I hope I am making myself clear enough ...

So I came up with the following sketch of an idea but I don't know if it would work ? --> since such a thing as positionning targets exist for 3D scanning (although some expensive 3D scanners can do very well without them), I thought about sticking one positionning target at every spot on the helmet which I want to be particularly recognized. Since they make pretty small targets, I believe I could be down to the precision I want.

But here is the question: when you import a 3D scan into Blender for which there were positionning targets sticked on the subject, does Blender automatically detect them or does it treat the targets just like any other surface ? I guess this question depends heavily on the scanning protocol and on the scanner model, but I thought asking here might be relevant still. In principle I guess it just treats everything (targets included) as one surface, but maybe there is some specific protocol that can help a program like Blender automatically detect positionning targets in a 3D scan ? Maybe by color ?

As you can see I am in the very preliminary steps of what I want to achieve and I am fishing for possible directions in which to look for solutions. I'll answer any questions you guys may have if you need more specifics and I'll be grateful for any indications!

Thanks a lot!

Gustavo

Comment: The part about the recognition isn't clear to me. Blender doesn't perform image recognition. It will simply import the 3D model with its position and rotation as written in the file you're exporting from your 3D scanning application. Do you mean you want to segment the 3D mesh into different parts and create a clean topology?

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for answering. What I meant by "recognition" is simply this: I want to be able to select the vertices / faces corresponding to those little stickers (positionning targets or whatever else works), but of course I don't want to do this manually!

For example, when there is color / texture in the model, I believe one can select all vertices / faces that correspond to a certain material. And then one could simply add those vertices to a group and bingo, that's how I would like it.

Comment: You could select vertices that belong to a certain material, but the 3D scanning software will likely just output textures and use a single material.  There may also not even be vertices at the particular spot where the texture has the marker. So unless I've misunderstood your question, the answer is: No, this is not possible in Blender (unless you implement a Python add-on that performs image recognition to detect the markers in the texture and selects the nearest vertex to it in the mesh).

Comment: I see. I think I even have experimented what you say: I downloaded a 3D scan sample model from Artec3D which had color / texture, and I realized that, as you say, texture IS rendered but there is only one material covering most of the model (and then just an image file providing texture to the 3D model). Thank you for y our answers. At the very least, I know have a better understanding of how texture mapping works. 

I know this is no longer a Blender question, but would you guys know of any type of 3D scanning protocol which could help me achieve what I want ?